# Scenarios where Xml Serialization fail in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I would like to know the most common scenarios where xml serialization may fail in .NET.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959/net-xml-serialization-gotchas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking mainly of `XmlSerializer` here:

- it is limited to tree-like data; it can't handle full object graphs
- it is limited to public members, on public classes
- it can't really do much with `object` members
- it has some weaknesses around generics
- like many serializers, it won't touch instance properties on a collection (bad practice in the first place)
- xml simply isn't always a good choice for large data (not least, for performance)
- requires a public parameterless constructor

`DataContractSerializer` solves some of these, but has its own limitations:

- it can't handle values in attributes
- requires .NET 3.0 (so not much use in 2.0)

Comment: The public members issue can be worked around by using DataContractSerializer

Comment: These are all good things to know about the Xml Serialization framework in .NET, but I would not say they are common scenarios where XML Serialization "fails."   For example, that the Xml serializer serializes only public read/write members is an attribute of the serialization framework, not a scenario where it fails.  That it requires the class to have a public parameterless ctor is also not a "failure" per se.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot easily serialize generic collections.

See another question: [C# XML Serialization Gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959/c-xml-serialization-gotchas)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the serializer, cyclic references may not work

Answer (score 1):

Using the shadows keyword has also broken serialization and deserialization for me because the shadowing causes a new implementation of that property to exist making it incompatible for proper reconstruction.  Only use overloads if you want to retype to the specific for a subclass.

Comment: For those who don't know VB.NET, "`Shadows`" is equivalent to `new` in C#: `public new int PropertyName {get;set;}` where the base class has a `public virtual int PropertyName ...`.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeSpan` objects are not serializable. `IDictionary`-implementing types are not serializable either (although they *can* be serialized with some manual massaging).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, classes marked as [Obsolete] are not serialized by XmlSerializer since .NET 2.0