# Using types, declared in Web Service 1, in Web Service 2. Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, azure

I have WebService1. Class "MapObject" declared in WebService1's solution.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void GetRoute(MapObject from, MapObject to)
    {
        // Something here
        return;
    }
```

WebService2 is using methods of WebService1. Also, WebService2 has method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void TestMethod(MapObject obj)
    {
        /// something here
    }
```

But when I try to call TestMethod I recieve

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Индекс находился вне границ массива.
>      в System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
>      в System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
>      в System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

This is because MapObject can not be serialized, but I can not understand why.
I would like to know how I can solve this problem, if I need to use types of WebService1 in methods of WebService2.

Comment: MapObject can't be serialized.  Why?

Comment: I found a similar question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449398/asp-net-web-service-returns-indexoutofrangeexception-with-arguments)
I suggested that I have a problem of the same kind.

Comment: Does MapObject have a Dictionary<Herp,Derp> in it?

Comment: Nope, just 2 string propreties

Comment: Do you know what kind of serializer is being used? Not sure what the default is for web methods. See if you can find out, then try serializing/deserializing an example MapObject to see if anything throws.  Also, specify the full path of MapObject in case you are actually referring to a different type. Pull MapObject into its own assembly.  Reference it from both services so you are using the same exact type.  These are all guesses, as it is not clear from the error or your details why this is happening :/