# How do I get rid of the xmlns declarations inserted by the XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-declaration

I have this type:

```
[Serializable, DataContract]
public class A
{
  [DataMember(Order = 1)]
  public int P1 { get; set; }
  [DataMember(Order = 2)]
  public XmlSerializableDictionary<string, string> P2 { get; set; }
}
```

Where `XmlSerializableDictionary` is borrowed from [.NET XML serialization gotchas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67959/net-xml-serialization-gotchas).

The `XmlSerializer` produces the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <P1>17</P1>
  <P2>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string>Hello World!</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <string>xo-xo</string>
      </value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>
        <string>Good Bye!</string>
      </key>
      <value>
        <string>xi-xi</string>
      </value>
    </item>
  </P2>
</A>
```

The only things that I wish to get rid of are the xmlns declarations on the root element. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: btw, `XmlSerializer` uses none of `[Serializable]`, `[DataContract]` or `[DataMember]`

Comment: I know Marc. Those are for protobuf-net (except Serializable) :-).

Comment: lol; I didn't even spot that it was you asking, else I would have put two-and-two together. I just saw the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via `XmlSerializerNamespaces`:

```
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", ""); // this line is important... honest!
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(type);
    ser.Serialize(destination, obj, ns);
```

Comment: but this only if he wants to save it to File. tha WCF should do it for you. I think thats what he meant.

Comment: @Royi and at what point is WCF mentioned? Indeed, WCF *would not use* `XmlSerializer` for that (under a standard configuration) - it would use `DataContractSerializer`

Comment: ,I just saw the DataContract attr , so i related this to WCf.

Comment: Folks, do not forget protobuf-net. It uses DataContract too! Marc is a witness.