# Serialize an Typed object that contains an object of Type Object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to serialize an object which contains other objects but where the Type is not defined, like this :

```
public A
{
    public B attributeB;
    public C attributeC;
}

public A
{
   public object obj;
   public string str;
}
```

When trying to serialize an instance of Class A I get the error : "The type xxxx was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

Do you have any idea if this is possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003585/type-xxxx-not-expected-use-xmlinclude-or-soapinclude

Comment: Thanks it's what I needed