# XmlSerializer throws an exception on deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I stumbled upon a problem with the .NET XmlSerializer.
Whenever I try to deserialize some of my projects classes I get an `FileNotFound`-Exception with the following message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'mscorlib.XmlSerializers, Version=2.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I know that I get that exception because I disabled the "Just My Code"-Option in the visual studio. I actually want to get that exception so I can make sure I generate an XmlSerializers.dll for the project that it's missing for, but as you can see in this case it's the mscorlib.dll. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. When I use the sgen.exe and try to generate an XmlSerializers.dll for the project in which the class is that I am trying to deserialize I get some warnings, but the XmlSerializers.dll is generated. The class that is being deserialized has nothing special. It contains some properties of the following types

```
2x short
1x string
2x DateTime
1x List<short>
1x List<MyClass>
```

'MyClass' contains nothing special either, just some shorts, a string and one DateTime property.

I have other classes that basically have the same spectrum of datatypes and they deserialize just fine. Is this maybe a bug in the CLR?

I created a testproject and copied the 2 classes and deserialized them and got no exceptions.

My CLR Version is 2.0.

If you need more information on the subject let me know I would be glad to provide whatever you need if it helps me resolving this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Greetings,

Andre

**Update:**

Like *sll* requested here are the Classes

SerialzedClass:

```
public class SerializedClass
{
#region Constructor
/// <summary>
/// constructor for serialization only
/// </summary>
public SerializedClass() { }

/// <summary>
/// public constructor
/// </summary>
public SerializedClass(short id, string bez, DateTime updateY, DateTime updateX, short lastID)
{

  this.ID = id;
  this.Bez = bez;
  this.UpdateY = updateY;
  this.UpdateX = updateX;
  this.LoadedSprs = new List<short>();
  this.LoadedHandRefs = new List<TraderHandRef>();
  this.LastID = lastID;

} // SerializedClass

#endregion

public short LastID { get; set; }

public short ID { get; set; }

public string Bez { get; set; }

public DateTime UpdateY { get; set; }

public DateTime UpdateX { get; set; }

public List<short> LanguageIDs { get; set; }

public List<MyClass> MyClass { get; set; }

}
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass
{

#region Constructor

/// <summary>
/// constructor for serialization only
/// </summary>
public MyClass() { }

#endregion

#region Properties

/// <summary>
/// get/set KID value
/// </summary>
public short KID { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// get/set Date value
/// </summary>
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// get/set VID value
/// </summary>
public short VID { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// get/set description value
/// </summary>
public string Description { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// get/set ID value
/// </summary>
public short ID { get; set; }

#endregion
}
```

My deserialize call looks like this:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serial = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

where T represents SerializedClass.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundException for mscorlib.XmlSerializers.DLL, which doesn't exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135/filenotfoundexception-for-mscorlib-xmlserializers-dll-which-doesnt-exist)

Comment: the answer in that post didn't help my problem, I could've posted my question there though.

Comment: ok show code which actually does serialization and deserialization, are you deserializing exactly the same type which was serialized?

Comment: check original post, I added the classes and the serialization call

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an expected error.  [C# XmlSerializer BindingFailure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209443/c-xmlserializer-bindingfailure/2209878#2209878) describes the problem and why it occurs

Comment: Like I said on top of my post, I know that this error is expected when a XmlSerializers.dll is not available. The question is why is the mscorlib.XmlSerializers.dll not available at that point or what am I doing wrong that it's not being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the ***[Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*** attribute to your class.

```
[Serializable()]
public class SerializedClass
{
```

Comment: Hey Johnny, thanks for the down vote! I had the same exact issue last night and I solved it by added the Serialize attribute to my class.

Comment: Hey Mark, I have the Serializable attribute, it just looked weird in the post so I removed it, sorry.

Comment: No worries Andre, I was doing the same thing last night and I received the same (or similar) message. I isolated the class into a separate project and it worked fine but once I added the Serialize attribute it worked like a champ. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could try generating the serialization assembly for mscorlib:

```
REM In a Visual Studio Prompt:
sgen /a:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll /o:.\x32
sgen /a:C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll /o:.\x64
```

Comment: I am unsure about that Jonathan. Where would I put that generated serialization assembly? The output of my project is a Client application. As far as I know anyone with whatever version of .NET 2.0 could run this program and so some or most of the people would still have this problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AndreFly it would probably work directly in your client's directory; but you would need to retain two directories for x86 and x64 and wire them in with the probing configuration. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx

Comment: @AndreFly I think you a pretty much out of luck then :(.