# Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly.XmlSerializers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, xmlserializer

I took a memory dump of IIS and while analyzing i found the error that said **'Could not load file or assembly MyAssemblyName.XmlSerializers'**. In my code i am using XmlSerializer class to serialize and deserialize xml contents from xml file to custom object. When the project gets build it only creates MyAssembly.dll and MyAssembly.pdb file but not the MyAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll. Does anyone know how to enable my project to create xmlserializers.dll file?

**Note: In project build tab, 'Generate serialization assembly is set to Auto.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 72):

There's an answer already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127431/xmlserializer-giving-filenotfoundexception-at-constructor).  Apparently this is "expected behaviour" that MS isn't going to fix.

The first comment has a workaround:

> One of the possible ways to get rid of this problem is check "Just my code" option in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General options

Comment: This was a great help!  Who would have guessed that workaround.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: In VS 2022 the option is named `Enable Just My Code"

Answer (score 4):

You can also generate this assembly using **Sgen.exe**

For me it's located in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools`

```
1. open cmd command
2. cd yourProjectPath
3. sgen Project.dll
```

The following command creates an assembly named Project.XmlSerializers.dll for serializing all the types contained in the assembly named Project.dll.

Answer (score 2):

When you create MyAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll make sure it is same .NET version as your project. You can check that using software as dotPeek or ILSpy. I had similar problem when creating xmlserializers for my .NET 3.5 solution from visual studio, generate serialization assembly was set on for project but Sgen.exe was used from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools and should be from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin. 
If your solution is in .NET 3.5 MyAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll must also be in .NET 3.5

Comment: Dude; All code is in the same project - there is only one .NET version to rule them all :)