# Refrenced a ddl assembly file in c# but when i build the application and call on of the classed in the ddl file i get system unable to load

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm working on a C# project where I need to use an external DLL for a specific functionality. I followed the steps to add a reference to the DLL in Visual Studio, and I made sure that the "Copy Local" property is set to "True." However, when I try to use types and methods from the external DLL in my code, I encounter runtime errors, and the application can't find the DLL.

I've also confirmed that the DLL is not in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), and I've checked the output directory after building the project to ensure that the DLL is being copied there. Despite these efforts, I'm still facing issues accessing the external DLL from my project.

Could someone please guide me on how to resolve this issue? What might be causing the problem with locating and using the external DLL in my C# project?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug "Could not load file or assembly" runtime errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602912/how-to-debug-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-runtime-errors)

Comment: @NineBerry {
  "StatusCode": 500,
  "Message": "Could not load file or assembly 'IdentityGuardAuthServiceV11API.XmlSerializers, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified."
}

Comment: This is an error you can ignore. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755559/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-myassembly-xmlserializers

Comment: @NineBerry i can't ignore it its stopping my aplication from executing its major use which make use of a class from the assembly

Comment: It might stop debugging in Visual Studio because your Visual Studio is configured to do that, but a failure to load an "*.XmlSerializers.dll" dll is ignored at runtime usually

Comment: please add all required details to your question